# What is a simple way to combine grouped values in one field?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I mean:

```
Table PHONE_CODES:

ID CODE_NAME PHONE_CODE 
1   USA         8101
2   USA         8102
3   PERU        8103
4   PERU_MOB    81031
5   PERU_MOB    81032
```

And I want via select to get something like this:

```
CODE_NAME   ZONE_CODES
USA          8101; 8102;
PERU         8103
PERU_MOB     81031; 81032;
```

I could get it via the function below, but perhaps there is a better way:

```
select distinct(CODE_NAME) as CODE_NAME, get_code_names_by_ZONE(CODE_NAME) as ZONE_CODES from PHONE_CODES;
```

Function:

```
create or replace function get_code_names_by_ZONE
(
    ZONE_CODE_NAME in varchar2
)
return varchar2
as
    codes_list varchar2(4000);
    cursor cur_codes_list is
        select p.PHONE_CODE
        from PHONE_CODES p
        where p.CODE_NAME = ZONE_CODE_NAME;
begin

    for codes_list_rec in cur_codes_list
    LOOP
        -- dbms_output.put_line('PHONE_CODE:[' || codes_list_rec.PHONE_CODE || ']');
        codes_list := codes_list || codes_list_rec.PHONE_CODE || '; ';
    end loop;

    return codes_list;

    EXCEPTION 
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            return 'notfound';
        WHEN others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Error code:' || SQLCODE || ' msg:' || SQLERRM);
            return null;
end get_code_names_by_ZONE;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Hall has an excellent discussion on the various [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) that are available in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

A function would be my preferred method of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 11g, take a look at the new PIVOT extension to SQL - the best documentation looks to be in the Data Warehousing Guide section.  I believe however that the target of the  "... for  in ..." clause cannot be a subquery and has to be a hard-coded list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Good link Justin.  Tim hall is awesome.  I followed his advice and here it is:

```
  1  SELECT CODE_NAME,
  2     LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PHONE_CODES,';'))
  3     KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),';') AS PHONE_CODES
  4  FROM   (SELECT CODE_NAME,
  5         PHONE_CODES,
  6         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE_NAME ORDER BY PHONE_CODES) AS curr,
  7         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE_NAME ORDER BY PHONE_CODES) -1 AS prev
  8      FROM   a)
  9  GROUP BY CODE_NAME
 10  CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND CODE_NAME = PRIOR CODE_NAME
 11* START WITH curr = 1
SQL> /

CODE_NAME  PHONE_CODES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
PERU       8103
PERU_MOB   81031;81032
USA    8101;8102
```

dbBradley - I don't think the Pivot extension works here.  The Pivot extension requires the use of an aggregate (sum, count, ...).

Comment: I used COLLECT method - it seems to me the best and fastest option.
select PHONE_CODE, tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(FULL_PHONE_CODE) AS t_varchar2_tab), '; ') as cdf
 from phone_codes
  where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
    connect by prior phone_code_id = par_phone_code_id 
     group by PHONE_CODE;

Comment: I like it except for the need to create object type.  Which is not a bad thing if you use it often.  I just don't like to add objects to the DB if they are not required.  Less to document, remember, clean up later on ;-)